# Remove unique elements only

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-dif

There are many resources on how to remove duplicates and similar issues but I can't seem to be able to find any on removing unique elements. I'm using SWI-Prolog but I don't want to use built-ins to achieve this.

That is, calling `remove_unique([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 6, 7], X).` should happily result in `X = [2, 2, 7, 7]`.

The obvious solution is as something along the lines of

```
count(_, [], 0) :- !.
count(E, [E | Es], A) :-
  S is A + 1,
  count(E, Es, S).
count(E, [_ | Es], A) :-
  count(E, Es, A).

is_unique(E, Xs) :-
  count(E, Xs, 1).

remove_unique(L, R) :- remove_unique(L, L, R).
remove_unique([], _, []) :- !.
remove_unique([X | Xs], O, R) :-
  is_unique(X, O), !,
  remove_unique(Xs, O, R).
remove_unique([X | Xs], O, [X | R]) :-
  remove_unique(Xs, O, R).
```

It should become quickly apparent why this isn't an ideal solution: `count` is `O(n)` and so is `is_unique` as it just uses `count`. I could improve this by `fail`ing when we find more than one element but worst-case is still `O(n)`.

So then we come to `remove_unique`. For every element we check whether current element `is_unique` in `O`. If the test fails, the element gets added to the resulting list in the next branch. Running in `O(n²)`, we get a lot of inferences. While I don't think we can speed it in the worst case, can we do better than this naïve solution? The only improvement that I can clearly see is to change `count` to something that fails as soon as >1 elements are identified.

Comment: You can sort first (O(N*log(N))) and then remove unique elements (O(N)) and after that use binary search or a heap for each element to determine wether it is unique O(N * log(N))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`tpartition/4`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29867514/4609915) in tandem with
[`if_/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915) and [`(=)/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915), we define `remove_unique/2` like this:

```
remove_unique([], []).
remove_unique([E|Xs0], Ys0) :-
   tpartition(=(E), Xs0, Es, Xs),
   if_(Es = [], Ys0 = Ys, append([E|Es], Ys, Ys0)),
   remove_unique(Xs, Ys).
```

Here's the sample query, as given by the OP:

```
?- remove_unique([1,2,2,3,4,5,7,6,7], Xs). 
Xs = [2,2,7,7].                       % succeeds deterministically
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't know that the list is sorted in any way, and you want to keep the sequence of the non-unique elements, it seems to me you can't avoid making two passes: first count occurrences, then pick only repeating elements.

What if you use a (self-balancing?) binary tree for counting occurrences and look-up during the second pass? Definitely not  O(n²), at least...

Comment: A good suggestion, +1! Also check out the beautiful version of `list_to_set/2` by Ulrich Neumerkel, using sorting and unification to efficiently detect duplicate elements: [git commit](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/commit/0bbdbaf6d5d01dcf4b9ab864e111c7d8d7a481fc).